# Create standalone isolated python

Tags: python, dependencies

I'm to deploy Python into a production system and the python script I have has a number of modules associated with it.

Is there a way to install python with only a specific list of modules? Abit like with generating a jar, you can have a folder with all the other dependency jar's in a folder, which is nice and clean. I don't want to compile the python code so I want something similar.

(Note: I also don't want to create a virtual environment - I want the default environment like this)

Comment: Anaconda, Docker etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), which basically is what the name suggests, or you can use Docker, which personally I prefer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do like what Amir is suggesting above, then 2 other options are available:

1. Copy those modules and place them in the same folder where your script is installed
2. Create a requirements.txt file with the name & version of those modules and then run "pip install -r requirements.txt" to install these modules in your site-packages folder

Answer (score 1):

To manage your python packages you can use great **virtualenv** tool, it looks really simple and works well on *linux/macOS/Windows*. Any package which will be installed in **activated virtualenv** will be **available only in this virtualenv**, so you can have for example 3 different versions of "Django" package on your machine and work with them using different virtual environments:

Install virtualenv:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```

Create your virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 my_virtualenv_name
```

Activate your virtualenv:

```
$ . my_virtualenv_name/bin/activate
```

Check what packages have been installed:

```
$ pip freeze
```

Install any package for example "Django":

```
$ pip install Django
```

Confirm installation:

```
$ pip freeze | grep Django
```

Uninstall any package from your virtual environment:

```
$ pip uninstall Django -y
```

Uninstall all packages from your virtual environment:

```
$ pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Deactivate virtualenv

```
$ deactivate
```

More info in the official documentation: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/